# Why is emacs indenting with tabs even though indent-tabs-mode is nil?

Tags: indentation

In C/l-mode F1 v indent-tabs-mode prints:

```
indent-tabs-mode is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is nil
Original value was t
Local in buffer nir_types.cpp; global value is t
```

But pressing the tab key still replaces the spaces used for indentation with tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was smart-tabs-mode which was making life miserable as I have it turned on by default in my init.el.

Turning it off locally for the specific project solved all my troubles. I.e. in .dir-locals.el in the source code parent folder I wrote:

```
((prog-mode
  (indent-tabs-mode . nil)
  (smart-tabs-mode)))
```