# How to reveal tabs in the indentation in a cpp file?

Tags: indentation, whitespace, tabs

My friend and I collaborate on a C++ project and we agree to use 4 whiltespaces for indentation. I am using Emacs and this is my indentation setting

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
```

By doing this, I believe that I can use tab safely without pressing the space bar for 4 or 8 or 12 times. However, my friends (Eclipse user) and I see awkwardly indented (misaligned) code in our own code editor. Then we accuse each other for using tabs instead of 4 whitespaces.

How can I find the ground truth in our cpp file? We want to know who introduces `\t` to our code.

We use svn for source control and do not have a nice UI for code review. So I prefer to check this `\t` character locally.

Comment: Related search here on emacs.se: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=indent-tabs-mode Note, there are situations where `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` has not the desired effect, e.g. when [`smart-tabs-mode`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24424/why-is-emacs-indenting-with-tabs-even-though-indent-tabs-mode-is-nil) is activated by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should set the default value of `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil`.
Either [toggle it off with customize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) or put the following lisp code into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```el
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

You can check for tabs in a file with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `white-space-mode` in its buffer. Tabs are indicated with `»` when that mode is active.

If you want to prominently highlight tabs permanently you can use the following code from [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace#toc9) in your init file.

```el
;; Draw tabs with the same color as trailing whitespace  
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook  
      (lambda ()  
        (font-lock-add-keywords  
         nil  
         '(("\t" 0 'trailing-whitespace prepend)))))
```