# setq require-final-newline not working when setq-default does

Tags: init-file, whitespace, newlines

I want all my files to end with only one newline, while trimming trailing whitespaces on regular lines.

Like so : ($ is newline face)

```
text$
$
last_line$
```

I use `whitespace-cleanup` in my init file, like so :

```lisp
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup)
```

With whitespace-style :

```
(face tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab
 newline indentation empty space-after-tab
 space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)
```

To keep newlines I add :

```lisp
(setq require-final-newline t)
```

Then `eval-buffer` my init file.
But Emacs does not take my setting unless I use `setq-default`. There is no mention in `require-final-newline` documentation that it is buffer local.

Comment: @NickD Can you elaborate? there is nothing in documentation of `require-final-newline` that hints variable is buffer local
@jue : replace q.uestions in NickD's link

Comment: (Can't do anything right today - I guess I added a period inadvertently. Thanks for pointing it out). See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58104

Comment: I thought 'keep one newline at end of file' was one newline alone on last line, when it actually means one newline after last character of last line. I edit question as problem shifted to setq-default behavior.

Comment: @JohnDoe with your new edit, I can't see what is your question now.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I'm as confused as you are. It quacks like a buffer-local, but I'm probably missing something (it's been that kind of a day...), so I don't think I should even try to elaborate, even if I could.

Comment: @JohnDoe:  I did some research and I've summarized my current understanding in the new answer, although it's not quite complete: there is a leap of faith in there. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either set the default value of the variable, if you want it for every file:

```el
(setq-default require-final-newline t)
;; or ...
(customize-set-variable 'require-final-newline t)
```

or to set it in the mode hook, if you only want it for files of that mode:

```el
(add-hook 'some-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local require-final-newline t)))
```

---

The reason that a bare `(setq require-final-newline t)` does not work is that `require-final-newline` is buffer-local in certain cases. A number of modes (most prominently `prog-mode` and `text-mode`) do this:

```el
(setq-local require-final-newline mode-require-final-newline)
```

That also affects their derived modes (e.g. `emacs-lisp-mode` in the first case and `org-mode` in the second). So in those modes, `require-final-newline` is indeed buffer-local.

I don't know exactly how the loading and evaluation of the init file happens, but if it happens in such a buffer (e.g. in an `emacs-lisp-mode` buffer), `require-final-newline` is indeed a buffer-local, so the `setq` does not change the global default and your (future) buffer does not see the changed value. I suspect (but I don't know for sure) that this is the underlying cause of the failure of the bare `setq` in your init file and why you need `setq-default`.

EDIT: In answer to your question in the comment, I don't think there is a way to ask whether the variable is buffer-local in any buffer that exists in the current session, except by checking *every* buffer.

The problem is that *any* variable can be made buffer-local in a particular buffer, and nobody would know about that except that particular buffer: if you try to`setq` from that buffer, you would only change the local value. So if you ask about the variable anywhere except in that buffer, it would say "not local". There are two functions `local-variable-p` and `local-variable-is-set-p` that do this kind of asking and they both say `nil` for a buffer in e.g. `fundamental-mode` for the variable `require-final-newline`. You can check for local-ness in other buffers so you could write something like this to check *every* buffer:

```el
(defun is-local (sym)
  (catch 'found
    (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
      (when (local-variable-p sym buf)
        (throw 'found t)))
    nil))
```

If you evaluate `(is-local 'require-final-newline)` in *any* buffer, it says `t`, because it *is* local in the `*scratch*` buffer e.g.

But even this is not completely reliable: if during initialization a buffer is created and makes `require-final-newline` buffer-local but then gets deleted, the loop above will not find it afterwards. If there is no other buffer with a buffer-local `require-final-newline`, the function says `nil`. You can check that by setting `initial-major-mode` to `fundamental`, in a small init file that also contains the function above and the `setq` of `require-final-newline`, and invoking emacs with `emacs -Q -l /path/to/minimal.init.el`. The `*scratch* buffer is now in fundamental mode and no other existing buffer (minibuffer, the` *Messages* buffer etc) makes the variable buffer-local, so the function happily says `nil` - but the `setq` still does not work. To me, that indicates that the scenario I've been describing here is correct (but I can easily imagine being Horatio to someone's Hamlet :-) ).

Comment: Is there any way when looking up a variable in emacs help to know if it has buffer-local values?